# Sym-1: What is the "f" register?

Tags: 6502, sym-1

Running `SUPERMON` on a Synertek [SYM-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SYM-1), the `R` (`REG`) command cycles through a number of registers. Most are self explanatory:

- `p` is the program counter (`pc`)
- `s` is the stack pointer
- `a`, `x`, and `y` are obvious

But what is `f`?

```
.r
P 8B4A,>
S   FF,>
F   00,>
A   00,>
X   00,>
Y   00,
.
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The only thing missing from your list of processor state is the flags register.

Comment: Thank you for helping my feeble brain. In my head I think "status register", not "flags register".

Comment: Brilliant Answer :))

Comment: In 6502 assembly, the status flags register is given the initial P (`PHP` and `PLP`).  Both P and S are already used to denote the Program Counter and the Stack Pointer in `SUPERMON`, so F is the next logical choice and is indeed available.